# Laser, detector and rocket

Tags: acceleration, relativity, inertial-frames

Imagine a setup whereby the laser is placed horizontally inside a rocket and points toward a detector which tells the rocket to accelerate. However from an outside observer inertial frame of reference he will notice the light is being bends, so does the rocket still accelerate? (assume constant acceleration and no outside forces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, the light will certainly make contact with the detector at the beginning of the situation, but whether or not it will continue to do so is dependent on the magnitude of the acceleration.

When a photon is fired from the origin towards the detector, it will appear to, from all locally inertial reference frames, follow a straight path. If the rocket is *not* accelerating, as in the beginning of the scenario, then the photon will reach the detector without deviation. If, however, the ship is accelerating, the detector may be accelerated out of the path of the photon (depending on the size of the detector, the acceleration of the ship, and the distance between the origin and the detector).

I think you have a misunderstanding about this situation. If the rocket is accelerating, observers inside and outside the rocket will both perceive the laser beam to curve as it travels between it's origin and the detector.

Interestingly, even though the laser beam will not travel straight to the center of the detector after the first contact (because of the rocket's acceleration), there are actually two possible situations which could occur.

Where

- $a$ is the acceleration of the rocket
- $a_T$ is the acceleration threshold such that the detector will 'outrun' the laser (example calculation below)

if

1. $a\lt a_T$

   - The rocket will maintain a constant acceleration $a$.
2. $a\ge a_T$

   - The rocket will accelerate periodically.

**Description of Case 2**

If $a = a_T$, the rocket will accelerate such that the first photon that was fired after the initial photon made contact with the detector will pass just under the trailing edge of the detector. Once this occurs, the acceleration of the rocket will (assuming instantaneous acceleration change) stop. After the first miss, all of the photons that had been emitted before the first photon missed the detector will also miss the detector, and the process will start again—fresh—with the first photon that was emitted after the first miss.

If $a \gt a_T$, the period of acceleration will be shifted such that a smaller amount of time will be spent with the rocket accelerating (though the same amount of time will be spent with constant velocity).

Note that in each case, the total time $T$ is the sum of the accelerating time $T_a$ and constant velocity time $T_c$, which can be calculated as:

$$T_a=\sqrt{\frac{2r}{a}}$$
$$T_c=\frac{d}{v}$$

where

- $r$ is the radius of the detector from the target point
- $a$ is the acceleration of the rocket
- $d$ is the distance from the origin to the detector
- $v$ is the velocity of the laser light, $c$

---

#### Calculating the threshold acceleration to avoid laser detection

Let's assume a circular detector with a radius $r=1\text{m}$ fixed at a distance $d=100\text{m}$ from the origin, where the laser is fired towards the center of the detector.

1. Calculate laser travel time

$$t=\frac{d}{v}=\frac{100\text{m}}{299792458\frac{\text{m}}{s}}=3.34\cdot 10^{-7}\text{s}$$

2. Calculate required acceleration

Because the initial forward component of the velocity of both the laser and detector are the same, we can disregard it:

$$r=\frac{a\cdot t^2}{2}$$
$$a=\frac{2r}{t^2}=\frac{2\cdot 1\text{m}}{{\left(3.34\cdot 10^{-7}\text{s}\right)}^2}=1.78\cdot 10^{13}\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}^2}$$

Comment: Yes you read my question correctly :)